# Is there a way to find out what headers were sent?

Tags: php, node.js, express, http-headers

We all have encountered `Headers already sent` error probably. But I wonder if there's a way to find out what headers were sent?

Comment: that just means that A response was already triggered... sometimes, this can be caused by just having a space outside of the <?php ?> tags where you aren't expecting it

Comment: you tagged this with both PHP and node... what are you using?

Comment: thats probably your script already send a response and then set a header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: No. I wonder if there's a way to find out what exactly has been sent already.

Comment: from php to node or node to php ??

Comment: Ensure that the first characters are <?php
Ensure that the last characters are either NOT a PHP closing tag or a closing tag ?> with no blank lines or spaces after it.

Comment: You can use [headers_sent()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) to check if/where headers have been sent and [headers_list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to get a list of headers sent (or ready to send)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `ob_start();` on this page at the begging of the line after `<?php` tag.